# how to add sound in video with.avi extention in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, audio, video

I'm developing the project on videowatermarking using c#.net. I'm creating the video from .bmp file.

I'm able to create the video using avi manager in .avi extension but not able to add the sound to it video is created without sound....taking sound of .wav extension

Comment: can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, may be this is useful for you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library

Comment: yes i had looked in to this in this source code the same issue occur of video is been created with out sound it urgent plz hlep me out ..